# change default path of django administration

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I am new to Django. I am using django administration for basic crud purpose. 
I found that template for django admin resides at

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin
```

I need to change  it as my own location .. i created one folder "template" on base dir of project and added following lines

```
STATIC_URL =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')+'/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

i copied all files from `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates` to `basedir/templates`

but still it is referencing to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates`

what is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,hope this helps you

```
import os

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

...

#MEDIA_ROOT = PROJECT_PATH + '/media/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_PATH + '/templates/'
)
```